# Mi aplicación no ejecuta en Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, archivo, task, task-runner

El archivo .exe que tengo que ejecutar lee datos de un archivo de texto para su funcionamiento. Este archivo, se encuentra en la carpeta de Release con el archivo que tiene que leer ("Datos.txt"). El problema es que, cuando programo en Task Schedule que se ejecute, no encuentra el archivo "Datos.txt". Sin embargo, al ejecutarlo por fuera, sí encuentra el archivo y todo funciona correctamente. ¿Qué puede estar fallando? ¿Será en la parte del código o tal vez en la configuración de Task Scheduler?
Anexo una parte del código en el que se lee el archivo:

```
public static void readData()
    {
        //TextReader readFile;
        string chain;
        string fileName = "Datos.txt";
        string fullPath;

        fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);




        //bool found = false;
        string[] fields = new string[2];
        char[] breakUp = { ':' };
        try
        {

            using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(fullPath))
            {


                // chain = readFile.ReadLine();



                while ((chain = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    fields = chain.Split(breakUp);
...
```

Comment: La ruta puede estar mal, cambialo por algo asi, dependiendo donde este tu archivos "C:\\Release\Datos.txt"

Comment: Tu problema posiblemente radique en el ''Iniciar en'' del programador de tareas, prestale atención a eso, y sino redefiní tu `Path` por `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,Datos.txt)`, de esa manera debería encontrarlo